# Is there a way to create a role in a asp.net web API using the entity public bool IsUser { get; set; } = false;

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

This is my User class
public class User
{

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [PasswordPropertyText]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Parcel> Parcels{ get; set; }
    public bool IsUser { get; set; } = false;
```

I am developing two separate apps which are a mobile app(IsUser= true)and an Admin portal/web(IsUser=false) using asp.net web Api
But I am finding dificult implementing the role based authorization

Comment: Are you trying to pass  `IsUser` property from app to api or reverse?

Comment: No am passing from api to app